# Getting this error in run the hybrisserver

Tags: java, eclipse, sap-commerce-cloud

log4j:ERROR Could not connect to remote log4j server at [localhost]. We will try again later.
ERROR [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DataSourceImpl] error connecting to DataSource having url jdbc:mysql://localhost/monsoon_qa?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8: Access denied for user 'monsoon'@'localhost' to database 'monsoon_qa'
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'monsoon'@'localhost' to database 'monsoon_qa'

Comment: People are more likely to answer if you actually ask a question and say what you've tried so far to resolve this and what the outcome has been.

Answer (score 3):

looks like you have forgotten to grant the appropriate rights (or not created the user at all?) that is configured to connect hybris to mysql.

You have to create it somehow like this:

```
create database dbName CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin; 
create user 'theUser'@'localhost' identified by 'thePassword';
grant all privileges on dbName.* to 'theUser'@'localhost';
```

in your local.properties file you need to add an appropriate mysql configuration, something like this:

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8&innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.username=theUser
db.password=thePassword
```

Hope that helps.

**Note** that this is just example information. If you want to setup your hybris for a production system you might have to do a few more things, but for a development setup this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem. The solution is initialize database. Run the following command

```
sudo service mysql start
```

if this command doesn't work run it again and run the following command(for control)

```
sudo service mysql status
```